# Short story of a lone person at a military outpost/station that may have the quote "Hello, Brother" near the beginning

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, warfare, communication

This was published in an anthology I read in 1975. The anthology may have been fairly recent at that time (new or 2-3 years old).

Plot: The lone person is viewing a video of the person who was there before him, but died in battle. This person may have been something like the 10th person to be posted out there in the station. The video starts with the previous person saying "Hello, Brother" and then offering some other words of wisdom on being alone and responsible. The duty of the lone person is to respond and defend the outskirts of the claimed space. Of course an attack comes. The first thing the newbie does is remember protocol and notify command. He then proceeds to deploy defenses. Each side has many flying "units" that are deployed and used in the thrusts and parries of the battle. At the end he thinks he made a mistake and has lost, but the reinforcements arrive -- he had forgot that he had notified command.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is [Metal Gear Awesome](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwrPuCnNbv8) lol

Comment: It was not a film or video. It was a written short story. Thanks for the offer of help, though.

Comment: This sounds like the inspiration for Desmond and the Swan station in Lost, brother.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the story you are looking for is called *Steel Brother* by Gordon R. Dickson. I have it in the anthology "Orion's Sword: The Future at War, Vol. 3".

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You are correct gymbrall.
Thanks for your feedback. In fact I was thinking it was Gordon Dickson and looked through all my Dickson anthologies even before your feedback. I've always liked Dickson. It turns none of my anthologies have "Steel Brother". I originally read it in "The Book of Gordon Dickson". I got a few details wrong in the description. It was originally written in the early 1950's and holds up fairly well. Only a few anachronisms.

Comment: @OldSciFiReader Welcome back to the site. Since you have determined that this answer is correct, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. See the [faq#howtoask] for more details.

Comment: @OldSciFiReader
Glad to know that it's what you were looking for.